# C# - Convert Dictionary of Lists to List of Tuples with LINQ

Tags: c#, list, linq, dictionary

I have a Dictionary:

```
Dictionary<int, List<(byte Id, string name)
```

The structure of this dictionary would be something like:

```
{
[1, {(1, "Leo"), (2, "Messi")}]
[2, {(3, "Cris"), (4, "Ronaldo")}]
}
```

How can i convert it into into the following using LINQ:

```
List<(int, byte)>
```

So the structure becomes something like:

```
{
(1,1),
(1,2),
(2,3),
(2,4),
}
```

TIA.

Comment: what have you *tried* so far? show us your efforts.

Comment: Check out `SelectMany` it's how you can flatten internal collections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that your dictionary declared in the following way

```cs
var dict = new Dictionary<int, List<(byte Id, string name)>>
{
    {1, new List<(byte Id, string name)> {(1, "Leo"), (2, "Messi")}},
    {2, new List<(byte Id, string name)> {(3, "Cris"), (4, "Ronaldo") }}
};
```

You can convert it to `List<(int, byte)>` using [`SelectMany`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=netframework-4.8) method

```cs
var list = dict.SelectMany(kvp => kvp.Value, (pair, tuple) => (pair.Key, tuple.Id)).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks Pavel, this is exactly what i was looking for!